# UISplitViewController - is it a good idea to use storyboard segues to replace the detail view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController set up in my project. I basically have a static master table view controller and multiple detail view controllers for each of the row.

What I did to hook up the Master table view and the multiple detail views was creating replace segues from the master table view to each of the detail view controllers.

I then use `[self performSegueWithIdentifer:]` method for each of the rows in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the master table view controller.

I want to know if this a good way of doing this, or if there is a better way.

Because with this way, what if I have already selected the first row and I select the first row again? Wouldn't it call the `[self performSegueWithIdentifer: firstRowDetailViewSegue]` repeatedly as I tap on that row even though the firstDetailView is already on-screen? Wouldn't that cause performance issues over time if the user kept on tapping that specific row?

Comment: No UISplitViewController is much better approach - it works for ipad only

Comment: @bhavyakothari Hi, I am using a UISplitViewController. My question: is it a good idea to use storyboard segues to replace the detail view if I have multiple detail view controllers as I described.

Comment: are you making app for iphone or ipad

Comment: it is an ipad project

Comment: go for UISplitViewController - you will be relieved from lot of hassles

Comment: sorry, but I think you misunderstood my question. I wasn't asking about using a UISplitviewController or not. I am already using it.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is exactly the recommended way. In Xcode 6, they use "Show Detail" segues from master instead of "Replace" (deprecated) but other than that, you are doing it the right way.

The only other viable way is to swap nav controllers manually, but there are memory issues associated to nav swapping so what you are doing is the recommended way.